# How do i include icon in android studio like we used to do in eclipse before starting the project?

Tags: android, android-studio

I tried making a project on android studio.. but didn't find similar to eclipse. Icon option does not appear in the starting the project.

Comment: you checked my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Right Click on the **res**

select **new -> Image Asset**

In `Directory Structure` tab, **/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi** will highlighted by default.

Select it, a new window will be popped from where you can import and set icons for

**1.** Launcher Icons
**2.** ActionBar and Tab Icons
**3.** Notification Icons

Answer (score 0):

To create a new Android icon set, right click on a drawable folder and invoke "New > Image Asset".